# How can I add Console dll file in web application?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, webforms, console-application, dllimport

By following the CHATGPT guidelines I added a Console file dll (**Inboundnightlybatchfile** is my console file) in the bin folder of my web application. To access  the dll need to import in our application. So I write this **using Inboundnightlybatchfile;** But the dll file name does not appear in the IntelliSense, and it throws a compile time error.

[image: Click here to see the image reference]

I want to add the Console file dll to an Web application

Comment: Is this DLL a .NET assembly?  What namespace(s) does its code use?  Where did this DLL come from and what documentation exists for how to integrate it into your application?  How are you referencing the DLL in your application?

Comment: Hi David, Yes it;s a >NET assembly file. The namespace of the DLL file is "Inboundnightlybatchfile". By adding a reference file in my web application, get the data from the DLL, By clicking on the Add reference., and "using Inboundnightlybatchfile;" writing this line of code in my application to access the DLL file.

Comment: The bot isn't mature enough to teach you what is .NET and C#, so you should use search engines to find great books/tutorials to get started. The error you met clearly is a C# beginner mistake (you missed `;` to end the line), and you didn't add the assembly as project dependency in project file (as the very old assembly reference) either. That's why Visual Studio won't know the existence of the things defined in this assembly and cannot show them in IntelliSense.

Answer (score -1):

Well, HOW do you share ANY code in your existing application, or code from "other" applications?

Why of course, you have/put that code in a class.

I mean in your project now, how do you use/enjoy a bunch of helper code and routines?

You wind up with a class, and then in code create a instance of that class.

So, say I have a class that holds some information about a hotel?

Then you add a class to your project, and then simple use that class in code.

So, say this class:

```
Public Class Hotel

    Public HotelName As String
    Public City As String
    Public HotelDescripiton As String
    Public FirstName As String
    Public Lastname As String


    Public ReadOnly Property FullName As String
        Get
            Return FirstName & " " & Lastname
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Then in code, you can use that "code"

eg:

```
    Dim OneHotel As New Hotel

    OneHotel.HotelName = "Super 8 Hotel"
    OneHotel.FirstName = "John"
    OneHotel.Lastname = "Smith"

    Debug.Print(OneHotel.FullName)
```

Output:

```
John Smith
```

Same goes for a console application. If you want share that code, then move the console code you want to share to a class.

Say I have this console application. When I run it, it will display all my drives on the computer.

So, from command prompt I have this:

[image]

So, now let's say I want to use above in my web site - to display/list all the hard drives.

So, the code for above console application is this:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim cMyCode As New clsSharedCode

    Dim sDriveList As List(Of String)
    sDriveList = cMyCode.GetDrives

    For Each s As String In sDriveList
        Console.WriteLine(s)
    Next

End Sub
```

But, the "working" code for that console been moved to a class called clsSharedCode.

That is this:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class clsSharedCode

    Public Function GetDrives() As List(Of String)

        Dim DriveList As New List(Of String)

        Dim allDrives As DriveInfo() = DriveInfo.GetDrives

        For Each d As DriveInfo In allDrives

            Dim s As String
            s = $"Drive:{d.Name} Volume:{d.VolumeLabel} Type:{d.DriveType} Ready:{d.IsReady}"
            DriveList.Add(s)

        Next

        Return DriveList

    End Function


End Class
```

OK, so now let's use above in our web site. We simple set a reference to vbconsole.exe.

So, now this web page markup:

```
 <h3>Drives on computer</h3>
 <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="223px" Width="423px">
 </asp:ListBox>
```

code behind

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        Dim cConsoleCode As New VBConsole.clsSharedCode
        Dim sDriveList As New List(Of String)
        sDriveList = cConsoleCode.GetDrives

        For Each sDrive As String In sDriveList
            ListBox1.Items.Add(sDrive)
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

And then we get this:

[image]

So, to "share" code? How this works EVEN with a simple plain-Jane console application is quite much the same as you "always" done this.

This does mean/suggest that the working code in your console application should be moved out to a shared code class that BOTH the console application, and now your web application can use and enjoy.

But, be a web site, or even a simple console application?

The why and how of sharing the code is much is the same in .net. You share code by using a object approach, and this is quite much the WHOLE foundation as to how .net code works - including that of sharing code between systems and applications.

So, in my web application, I simple set a reference to vbconsole.exe, and now I am free to use + consume any code in that console application. However, as noted, like you ALWAYS done to share code? You will as a general rule move that code out to a class, and then any other application is free to consume + use that code by using the public class code you have in that application. So, that MySharedCode class in the console application can now be used by any other .net application, include that asp.net web site.

So, .net is "primarily" an object-based system, and this is the main pillar and foundation of how you re-use and share .net code. You share such code by creating class(s) with that code, so then your existing application (the console application) can use those class(s), and as above shows, by a simple reference to the vbconsole.exe application, the web site can also use + enjoy + consume that code also.

So, because a class forces you to separate out the UI parts from the code parts, then even adopting this approach in a simple console application means that such code can be used + consumed by any type of application. You can write another console application, and reference our above console application and use that code.

But, we can also create a windows desktop program, and again reference the vbconsole.exe application. And so can our web-based application.

And even MORE amazing? You can consume the above class in c#, or vb.net, and again it doesn't matter!